# how can I get value from a jquery tools?

Tags: jquery, html

Buttons minus and plus in input :http://www.bootply.com/ZnFpCtZhOa

```
<div class="xxx" data-name="quantity" data-value="2" data-id="80"></div>
```

how can i get value from div tag?

Comment: Use `$('div[data-id="80"]').data('value');`

Comment: You can use filter and attr method in Jquery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('.xxx').change(function(){
  alert($(".xxx input").val());
        });
```

add separate class for each spinner

or This is best solution for you

```
$('.xxx').change(function(){
  alert($(this).find( "input" ).val());
        });
```

I hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.attr()` method in JQuery.

```
$('div').filter(function(){
alert($(this).attr('data-name'));
});
```

**Js fiddle Demo :** [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/rajeeshmenoth/L58d1nj0/)